# Is iCloud data protection only secured by device passcodes in the event of an Apple server side breach?

Tags: apple, icloud

I'm trying to understand the security model of iCloud data protection, including the new advanced data protection which expands it to almost all iCloud data.

When restoring on a new device, given that no other devices are available, it is (AFAIK) possible to restore an encrypted iCloud backup using a passcode from a previous (now offline) device.

This seems to imply that somewhere on Apple servers there is some key data only encrypted using this passcode, so that in the event of a total breach of iCloud servers, it would be possible to brute-force user's iCloud data through the passcode?

This would further imply that all device passcodes need to be quite strong if protection against server breaches is desired. Is my understanding correct, or is there some clever cryptography protecting against this?

Comment: How about googling? Search for *"icloud data encryption"* gives highly relevant answers like [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202303). I suggest to close the question.

Comment: @mentallurg Are you refering to e.g. this quote: "If you lose access to your account, only you can recover this data, using your device passcode or password, recovery contact, or recovery key."

And interpreting that to mean that yes, the passcode is subject to offline brute force cracking in the event of a server breach?

Comment: What do you mean by *"is subject to offline brute force cracking"*? If you mean it *can* be successfully brute-forced, then such statement is *not true*. If you mean that one can *try* to brute-force, then yes, one can *try* to brute-force *any* encrypted data, not only iCloud data.

Comment: What I mean is in the original question. To be specific, say a user has used a 4 or 6 digit pin for their iPhone, as is common, does that mean that an attacker only needs to brute force that 4 or 6 digit pin to gain access to all encryption keys? That is of course completely trivial to brute force.

Comment: Ask Apple. I *suppose* the decryption key is stored on the device (iPhone, iPad). After a few failed attempts the device will be locked. Without unlocking the device the only option is to brute-force the AES-128 encryption of the backup, which is impossible.